# SimpleDateFormat - Illegal pattern character 'o'

Tags: java, date

this is my code:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh hours, mm minutes and ss seconds.").format(new java.util.Date(milliseconds));`
```

I get this Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'o'
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to quote the words. Go read the javadoc.

Comment: Not using the format string correctly; [check out the examples in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: sometimes SO can be so confusing, why the downvote to this question? it is a completely valid programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) states

> **Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation.**
>   "''" represents a single quote. All other characters are not
>   interpreted; they're simply copied into the output string during
>   formatting or matched against the input string during parsing

Therefore `''` around whatever parts of your String you don't want interpreted, something like

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh 'hours', mm 'minutes and' ss 'seconds.'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Format String is not right. Have a look into doc and give the format string the way you want the formatting. [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

In your case following line will work.

```
    new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh 'hours', mm 'minutes and' ss 'seconds.'")
```

Use single quotes to avoid misinterpretation.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
String val = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(
                 "hh 'hours', mm 'minutes and', ss 'seconds.'").
                 format(new java.util.Date(100000));

System.out.println(val);
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Date Time and Patterns:

> Date and time formats are specified by date and time pattern strings.
>   Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z'
>   and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters representing
>   the components of a date or time string. **Text can be quoted using
>   single quotes (') to avoid interpretation.**